# Showing Amazon mechanical turk qualification test result

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I wish to set up an Amazon mturk qualification test with the capability of presenting the worker which questions they did wrong.

For example:

[image: question screenshot]

If they worker wrongly answers this question as "Same", I'd like to display another screen to prompt them that they indeed made a mistake and point how the reasons behind the correct answer.

I have looked hard on the amazon documentation site, with no avail. I also know that this is possible because I encountered qualification tests with the same functionality when I tried to take some qualification tests myself, notably from CrowdSource.

Comment: This functionality is not available in Qualification tests because they must use QuestionForm, unless that QuestionForm contains a java applet to perform the requested functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas' answer is the correct answer. You cannot retrieve the results of a QualificationTest in Amazon Mechanical Turk. Thomas' suggestion of a Java Applet as a "workaround" is viable, but would introduce a lot of complexity to you the Qualification creator.

If you decide to go that route, you'll want to use the `Application` tag, which is documented in the `QuestionForm` question type. You can see more about this here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html

It'll work something like the following:

```
<Application>
  <JavaApplet>
    <AppletPath>http://tictactoe.amazon.com/applets/</AppletPath>
    <AppletFilename>GameViewer.class</AppletFilename>
    <Width>400</Width>
    <Height>300</Height>
    <ApplicationParameter>
      <Name>game_id<Name>
      <Value>01523</Value>
    </ApplicationParameter>
  </JavaApplet>
</Application>
```

As an alternate suggestion, you might consider just creating a HIT (admittedly, you'll likely need to offer a reward to Workers, say $0.01) and ask Workers to complete this. Capture those who pass your test, and create a Qualification for just those Workers. That'll give you the full functionality of the HITs (HTML, IFRAME, etc) and you'll get all the results. The downside is that you'll likely have to pay Workers at least $0.01 to complete the Qualification, though this isn't strictly required (you can create a HIT and price it at $0.00).